# Sum data from a table between dates in another table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have these two tables that relate to each other with the column `itemid`.
I managed to make the sum of different `itemid` values as I show in the first example from `data_table`.

Now I want to relate this sum by specific dates in the other table but I can not. Please can anyone help me?

items_table

```
+--------+-----------+------------+
| itemid | published | publish_up |
+--------+-----------+------------+
|      1 |         1 | 02-01-2014 |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

data_table

```
+--------+---------+------+
| itemid | fieldid | data |
+--------+---------+------+
|      1 |      27 |    5 |
|      1 |      28 |   10 |
|      1 |      29 |    5 |
+--------+---------+------+
```

This query is ok:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='27')
     + (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='28')
     + (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='29')
```

But not between dates:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='27')
     + (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='28')
     + (SELECT SUM(data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid='29')    
WHERE  (publish_up BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
FROM   items_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT   itemid, SUM(data)
FROM     data_table JOIN items_table USING (itemid)
WHERE    publish_up >= '2014-01-01'
     AND publish_up <  '2014-02-01'
GROUP BY itemid
```

Comment: Well but use JDatabaseQuery to do it.

Comment: SELECT SUM (data) FROM data_table WHERE fieldid IN (SELECT itemid FROM items_table WHERE (publish_up BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00'))